# Identify a film with a scene containing extreme decompression

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a film on TV in the UK. It would have been in late 80s to early 90s, and I expect it to have been made in the same period of time.

It was a live action sci-fi film, in colour and English, set either on a space station, or a base underwater. It had a very dark atmosphere, almost like Aliens, as the films were around at the same time I would guess it may have been trying to copy Aliens a bit. Something happens on the space station / base and the people there are either being killed by something or each other.

The only scene that sticks in my mind with any strength is this:

> **At some point one of the people in the base attempts to escape. He makes it to an escape pod, straps himself in and ejects. However he missed out a step and didn't pressurise the pod correctly, as the pod is escaping you see blood starting to escape from his skin and he is trying to hold it in. I assume he dies.**

I dont know if this was at the end of the film or part way through.

*I know it isn't Event Horizon nor is it The Abyss.*

Comment: Hands down the goriest scenes of explosive decompression are from the 1981 sci-fi film *Outland*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8G2EM_L2nw. :-P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [**DeepStar Six**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeepStar_Six).

> After a hallucination of Van Gelder, Snyder jumps into the escape pod
>   and launches. Because he has not undergone decompression, the pressure
>   changes from the ascent cause him to burst.

**The Decompression Scene** (warning, not pleasant).

Comment: having just looked at wikipedia I saw this "Arming themselves with shotguns and harpoons with explosive carbon-dioxide cartridges," which I'd also forgotten happened. I have just looked at Snyders escape on Youtube and this is it! Thank you

Comment: Just so you know, the video is unavailable now.

Comment: @Spencer - Cheers. Sorted